# HOW can I make this TIMELINE ONLY using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the timeline from this website https://www.dealema.pt/biografia/ ONLY using HTML and CSS (NO librarys)? And NO javascript or anything, just pure HTML and CSS.

I did the first image + text responsive, but I'm having hard time adding the rest... The "timeline-02" invades "timeline-01".
I want to make this as simple as possible and still look as identical as the timeline from the website. Doens't need to be perfect, just good enough.

My HTML code:

```css
.timeline {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 115px;
  margin-bottom: 115px;

}

.timeline:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #181818;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.timeline-01 img {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.timeline-01-text {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.timeline-01-text p {
  color: #7e7e7e;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.timeline-01 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: -28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #181818;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .timeline:before {
    left: 10%;
  }
  .timeline-01 span {
    left: 10%;
  }
  .timeline-01 img {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .timeline-01-text {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 115px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="timeline">

  <div class="timeline-01">

    <img src="img/album-01.png" style="width: 170px; height: auto;">

    <span class="timeline-01-year">2006</span>

    <div class="timeline-01-text">

      <h2>EXPRESSO DO SUBMUNDO</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Entre rimas e batidas, nasce o primeiro trabalho dos Dealema, o mítico “Expresso do Submundo”. Uma obra de coleccionador que faz parte da história do hip-hop em Portugal e que foi recentemente reeditado em formato K7, uma prenda aos fãs que nunca
        tiveram acesso comercial a este disco.</p>

    </div>


  </div>



  <div class="timeline-02">

    <img src="img/album-01.png" style="width: 170px; height: auto;">

    <span>2016</span>

    <div class="timeline-02-text">

      <h2>EXPRESSO DO SUBMUNDO</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Entre rimas e batidas, nasce o primeiro trabalho dos Dealema, o mítico “Expresso do Submundo”. Uma obra de coleccionador que faz parte da história do hip-hop em Portugal e que foi recentemente reeditado em formato K7, uma prenda aos fãs que nunca
        tiveram acesso comercial a este disco.</p>

    </div>


  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp
This might help you

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti Thanks, still can't solve it... The second div "timeline-02" doens't separate itself from the "timeline-01", dont't know why.  If I make a div separeted from other div should't it be separated automaticly?